# https.request returning connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I use https.get with a url, it works perfectly. However, when using https.request with options, node returns `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`.

```
const requestClient = require('https')

async function getPromise(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const httpRequest = requestClient.request(options, (response) => {
            let dataChunks = []

            response.on('data', (dataFragments) => {dataChunks.push(dataFragments)})
            response.on('end', () => {
                let data = Buffer.concat(dataChunks)
                resolve(data.toString())
            })
            response.on('error', (error) => {reject(error)})
        })
        httpRequest.end()
    })
}

async function emailAuth() {
    let authOptions = {
        hostname: 'a.random.api',
        port: '8080',
        path: '/a/path?option1=1',
        method: 'GET'
    }

 let response = await getPromise(authOptions)
 console.log(response)
}
```

Why could this be happening?

Edit: I used `https.get` as follows:

```
const requestClient = require('https')

async function getPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const httpRequest = requestClient.get('https://a.random.api/a/path?option1=1', (response) => {
            let dataChunks = []

            response.on('data', (dataFragments) => {dataChunks.push(dataFragments)})
            response.on('end', () => {
                let data = Buffer.concat(dataChunks)
                resolve(data.toString())
            })
            response.on('error', (error) => {reject(error)})
        })
    })
}
```

Which responds immediately with the correct data

Comment: Can you show us how you are using `https.get` in the code that works?

Comment: Thanks! The difference appears to be that you're using the default port 443 with `https.get`, but a different port (8080) with `https.request`.

Comment: Ah alright, I'll try using 433

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I'm also facing this issue, even with explicitly using port 443.