# Connection Resets When Using https.request with Options in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

In NodeJS, when I use https.get(), my code works correctly, returning the required responses. But as soon as I switch over to https.request() with requestOptions, I get connection reset error, with the following stack trace:

```
err: {
  code: "ECONNRESET",
  stack: ""Error: read ECONNRESET\n    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)\n    at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)"
}
```

My code is below. Simply swap out the https.get & https.request:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const https = require('https');
const app = express();

app.all('/api/*', (req, res) => {
  forwardRequest(req, res);
});

app.listen(4600, () => {
  console.log('Proxy server listening on port 4600');
});

function forwardRequest(req, res) {
  const agolUrl = buildTargetUrl(req);

  const requestOptions = {
    port: 443,
    method: req.method,
    headers: req.headers,
  };

  // const proxyReq = https.get(agolUrl, (proxyRes) => {
  const proxyReq = https.request(agolUrl, requestOptions, (proxyRes) => {
    let responseData = '';
    proxyRes.on('data', (chunk) => {
      responseData += chunk;
    });
    proxyRes.on('end', async () => {
      doSomethingWithResponseData(responseData);
      res.writeHead(proxyRes.statusCode, proxyRes.headers);
      res.write(responseData);
      res.end();
    });

  }).on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('An error occurred with proxy.');
  });

  req.pipe(proxyReq); // What does this do?
}

function buildTargetUrl(req) {
  let targetUrl = 'https://some-remote-server.com' + req.originalUrl;

  targetUrl = decodeURI(targetUrl);

  targetUrl = targetUrl.replace('/api', '');

  return targetUrl;
}

function doSomethingWithResponseData(responseData) {
  // Custom logic here.
}
```

The dependencies are:

```
// Node version is v16.20.0
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "request": "^2.88.2"
      }
```

Note, this is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099185/https-request-returning-connect-etimedout) but unfortunately it doesn't have an answer yet, so posting a new one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out. It turns out in the headers, the target host "https://some-remote-server.com" does not like the `host` value (in my case, it was localhost).

Deleting the `host` from the header worked.